# How to do this Redux Thunk action creator in my special case with a React.createContext wrapper

Tags: reactjs, redux

I learn React Redux and Thunk and I need this action creator to use a Context.

I have this Redux action `asyncSaveUser` that works ok like this:

```
const asyncSaveUser = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(saveUserStart());
        ....Do lots of stuff...
};

export default asyncSaveUser;
```

But I need it to look like this: (Wrappen in the `withFirebase`)

```
const asyncSaveUser = ({ firebase }) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const userRef = firebase.userDoc(firebase.auth.currentUser.uid);
        dispatch(saveUserStart());
        firebase.db
            .runTransaction(transaction => {
                // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
                return transaction.get(userRef).then(doc => {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        return Promise.reject('Transaction failed: User dont exist!');
                    }
                    const newRoles = doc.data().roles;
                    // new roll
                    newRoles.push(ROLES.USER);
                    // remove roll
                    newRoles.splice(newRoles.indexOf('ANONYMOUS'), 1);
                    // save it back
                    transaction.update(userRef, { roles: newRoles });
                    return newRoles;
                });
            })
            .then(newRoles => {
                dispatch(saveUserSuccess(firebase.auth.currentUser));
                console.log(`Transaction successfully committed role(s): ${newRoles}`);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(saveUserFailure(error));
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
};

export default withFirebase(asyncSaveUser);
```

But when I do that the Redux Thunk does not detect `asyncSaveUser` as being an action creator and it's not being called.`

The `withFirebase` Context:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>{firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}</FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

This is how the `FirebaseContext.Provider` is assigned:

```
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase';
import store from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

So there is only one `new Firebase()` class. Singelton style one could say!.
So the only way to access it is through `withFirebase(asyncSaveUser)`

I understand that my problem comes from wrapping the action inside the `withFirebase` so the `asyncSaveUser` Thunk stop being a Thunk!

So how can I access my `Firebase` `provider`? Do I have to redesign from ground up?

**UPDATE**

I have tried this below code and it runs fine all the way to:
`return withFirebase(save);` then after that no breakpoint are hit inside the `save()`. I looks like I return an `const save = ({...` object but the code inside it is no runned so that's maybe why it does not work!??

```
const asynsaveUser = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const save = ({ firestore }) => {
            const userRef = firestore.userDoc(firestore.auth.currentUser.uid);
            dispatch(saveUserStart());
            firestore.db
                .runTransaction(transaction => {
                    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
                    return transaction.get(userRef).then(doc => {
                        if (!doc.exists) {
                            return Promise.reject('Transaction failed: User dont exist!');
                        }
                        const newRoles = doc.data().roles;
                        // new roll
                        newRoles.push(ROLES.USER);
                        // remove roll
                        newRoles.splice(newRoles.indexOf('ANONYMOUS'), 1);
                        // save it back
                        transaction.update(userRef, { roles: newRoles });
                        return newRoles;
                    });
                })
                .then(newRoles => {
                    dispatch(saveUserSuccess(firestore.auth.currentUser));
                    console.log(`Transaction successfully committed role(s): ${newRoles}`);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    dispatch(saveUserFailure(error));
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };

        return withFirebase(save);
    };
};

export default asynsaveUser ;
```

I renamed `asynSaveUser` to `saveUser` in this picture!

[image]

Hope you understand please advice?

Comment: Uhmm, I'm not sure, but you just passed an action creator inside a Higher Order Component. You should put your `asyncSaveUser` action inside the context first. And you should `export default asyncSaveUser`. `React.createContext({asyncSaveUser})` and then consume the created context.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, "You should put your asyncSaveUser action inside the context first." . Normally using HOC's is straight forward just wrapping them but not this time

Comment: @RishabhAnand Can you if you have time create and answer explaining this?

Comment: I updated my question with more code and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, I don't understand why the need for a Context-Provider and Context-Consumer approach when you're using a Redux - Action and Redux - Reducer type of approach.

Also, there a couple of mistakes.
First thing I noticed:
A Higher Order Component expects a Component in it's arguments, not an action creator.

A Higher Order Component adds extra properties (React `props`) to a Component.

The thing you're trying to achieve here is already done by the `connect` HOC provided by `react-redux` npm package.

```js
export const asyncSaveUser = ({firestore}) => dispatch => {
   const userRef = firestore.userDoc 
   ...
   // don't do any return withFirebase
   // just dispatch the corresponding actions this action creator has to
   // i.e, no need of a return statement anymore unless you want to quit execution 
   // of this function
   // eg: 
   dispatch({hello: 'hi', nice: 'same'});
}
```

Now in your `index.js` or `App.js` file or wherever you have asked `react` to `invoke` your `React` App

All you need is this

```js
<Provider store={store}>
   <App/>
</Provider>
```

Now let's say you have a component `Hello.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import {firestore} from './firebase';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {asyncSaveUser} from '../../redux/actionCreators/asyncSaveUser.js';
function Hello (props) {
  return (<button onClick={() => props.asyncSaveUser({firestore})}>Hello</button>);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {};
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
     asyncSaveUser: (stuff) => dispatch(asyncSaveUser(stuff)),
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```

The thing is you could make a HOC which adds only the `firebase` prop to your component, and in that HOC you'll still end up using the `connect` function from `react-redux`, so ... , there isn't really a point in making it as it will add unnecessary components in your `component tree` and hamper performance.

Hopefully this makes sense, or is of Value.

Comment: Thanks good ideas I learn much. Since I have this `new Firebase()` Singelton style baked into my `withFirebase(save)` wrapper HOC so I did not want to `props.asyncSaveUser({firestore})..` Anyway what I ended up doing while waiting for an answer here was to utilize the Thunk `withExtraArgument` like this `const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(firebase), initialiseSagaMiddleware];
` and I do that in App root when I create the React.createContext for the one and only  `new Firebase()`.. dunno if this is better or worse maybe I resolve to your solution will run some tests